# Creating an RVIZ plugin for a new display type

Tags: ros, rviz, messages, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

So for my project I created my own message type and was hoping to have it displayed in RVIZ. It is a slight adaptation of GridCells, but instead of containing a list of Points, it contains a list of a Point message that I created. The custom Point message contains two more pieces of information.

My problem is that the User Guide for RVIZ has told me that there is no API documentation. Is this still true? Is there any way for me to write a plugin? I think using RVIZ to display custom types of messages would make it even more powerful of a tool. Thanks for the help,

Blair

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40468/creating-an-rviz-plugin-for-a-new-display-type/) by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know the interface is still under development, so the API might not be stable, but there is a tutorial:

http://ros.org/doc/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html

Depending on what you want to display, there is always the option to send everything as a marker array. That should work all the time, if applicable.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating new `rviz` plugins is difficult and not encouraged.

There is a new [`rqt` project](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt) that provides a more general plugin interface. It should be better for new visualization work.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-08-18**:
Two years passed... so is still this the situation? We plan to create a graphical editor to add semantic information to 2D/3D maps, and a RViz plugin could be the ideal solution. Rqt plugins look great for simple interfaces, but we need the fully-fledged 3D interface that RViz provides. Thanks!!!

**Comment by [mpkuse](https://answers.ros.org/users/22134/mpkuse/) on 2015-08-05**:
Another year passed. Seems like there is no relief for plugin makers. I guess now they have these random tutorials but cannot seem to get the configuration correctly with catkin. The tutorials use ros_make. Anyone with experience???

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-08-05**:
@mpkuse the visualization tutorial package is a catkin package, you can use that as a template: https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/interactive_marker_tutorials